# Cannot access data from api

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I created function which returns me Object array, but I cant access data from it. Inside function it returns fine, but I need to reuse this function and access data it other components. 
I got this:

**Function**

```
export function useFetch(url: string) {
    const [state, setState] = useState({data: null, loading: true})

    useEffect(() => {
        const fetchData = async () => {
            const response = await fetch(`${API_URL}${url}`, {
                method: 'GET',
                mode: 'cors',
            });
            if(!response.ok){
                const err = await response.json();
                throw(err);
            }
            const data = await response.json();
            setState({data: data.data, loading: false});
        }
        fetchData();
    }, [])

    return state;
}
```

Inside my Project component a call it like this:

```
const { data, loading } = useFetch('/api/projects')
```

this works fine, but when I want to access some data from this array

```
{data.map(i => {
    return (
       <p>{i.id}</p>
    )
})}
```

I'm getting:

> Projects.tsx?d6a4:27 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'map' of
>   null

Comment: Try using conditional rendering data && data.map() or wrap with a conditional stament if (data !== null )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Issue is because of initialization, initial value of `data` is `null`, and you are trying to loop through it

```
useState({data: null, loading: true})
```

**Solution :**

Either use `[]`

```
useState({data: [], loading: true})
```

**OR**

If you want to keep it `null` , then check for data before looping it through :

```
{data && data.map(i => { // <---- HERE
    return (
       <p>{i.id}</p>
    )
})}
```